# django implement a product specifications feature

Tags: python, django, django-models, e-commerce

I am trying to to implement a product specifications feature where a product can have multiple specifications and specifications are grouped into groups which help in retrieving the correct specification for a given product but I am struggling to figure out how to link the models.

Here is a copy of my models.

```py
from django.db import models
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.files import File

#from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

# Category model
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


# Subcategory model
class Subcategory(models.Model):
    subcategory_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory_name

class ShippingDetails(models.Model):
    shipping_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    delivery_region = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    estimated_delivery_time = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Delivery to {self.delivery_region}: {self.estimated_delivery_time} days"

# Specification model (revised)
class Specification(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_shared = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key

# SpecificationValue model (revised)
class SpecificationValue(models.Model):
    specification_product = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    specification = models.ForeignKey("Specification", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=525, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('specification_product', 'specification'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.specification_product.product_name}: {self.specification.key} - {self.value}"

# SubcategorySpecification model (new)
class SubcategorySpecification(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey("Subcategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    specification = models.ForeignKey("Specification", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subcategory_specs')
    default_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.subcategory.subcategory_name}: {self.specification.key}"
# Product model
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField("Variation", blank=True)
    shipping_details = models.ForeignKey(ShippingDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    expiration_details = models.DateTimeField( null=True, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='Products/images/')
    specification_values = models.ManyToManyField(SpecificationValue, blank=True)
    subcategory_specifications = models.ManyToManyField(SubcategorySpecification, blank=True)
    regular_price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

    def get_shared_specification_values(self):
        return SpecificationValue.objects.filter(product=self, specification__is_shared=True)

    def get_subcategory_specification_values(self):
        return self.subcategory_specifications.all()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Open the saved image
        image_path = self.images.path
        try:
            # Open the image file
            with Image.open(image_path) as im:
                # Convert the image to WebP format and save it
                 im.save(image_path, "webp")
                 print("image successfully saved")
        except IOError:
            print(f"Unable to open or convert image: {image_path}")
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)


# OnSale model
class OnSale(models.Model):
    onsale = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    discount_percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product}: {self.discount_percentage}% off (from {self.start_date})"

# Promotion model
class Promotion(models.Model):
    onpromotion = models.BooleanField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    promotion_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    promotion_price = models.FloatField()

# Variation model
class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variation_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    variation_value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product} - {self.variation_name}: {self.variation_value}"



class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.product.product_name}'

class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=1)
    average_rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=1)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} added a review for {self.product.product_name}'
```

Comment: For dynamic properties on the products, you can use something like [`django-eav2`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-eav2) or [`django-jsonform`](https://github.com/bhch/django-jsonform). These have two completely different approaches to solving this problem. Choose the right one that fits your needs.